# Hier je ne savais pas quand est/était l’anniversaire de Julia

Tags: concordance-des-temps

Dans une énigme, peut-on faire dire à un personnage:

> Hier je ne savais pas quand *est* l’anniversaire de Julia.

ou faut-il:

> Hier je ne savais pas quand *était* l’anniversaire de Julia.

---

Oscar et Paul sont devenus amis avec Julia et ils veulent connaître le jour de son anniversaire. Julia leur a donné une liste de 10 dates possibles:
  3 mars, 4 mars, 5 mars,
  5 avril, 6 avril,
  4 mai, 6 mai, 8 mai,
  7 juin, 8 juin.

Julia dit le mois de son anniversaire à l'oreille d'Oscar, et dit le jour à l'oreille de Paul.

*Oscar* : Je ne sais pas quand est l’anniversaire de Julia, mais je sais que Paul ne sait pas non plus.
*Paul* : Au début je ne savais pas quand est l’anniversaire de Julia, mais maintenant je sais.
*Oscar* : Maintenant je sais aussi quand est l’anniversaire de Julia.

Quand est l'anniversaire de Julia ?

Comment: il faut clairement utiliser "était".

Comment: @Random Est-ce si clair ? Un présent de vérité générale peut rompre une concordance des temps, n'est-ce pas ? Et l'anniversaire de Julia n'a pas changé de date entre les deux. Je pense que nous avons besoin de justifier un peu mieux nos positions pour cette question. ;)

Comment: [Ce lien](http://www.cap-concours.fr/sanitaire-et-social/concours-paramedicaux/reviser/maitriser-la-concordance-des-temps-cc_fra_20) dit que le présent de l'indicatif peut s'employer en subordonnée d'une phrase au passé, notamment dans le cas de la vérité générale. [Slate.fr](http://www.slate.fr/story/100341/probleme-maths-singapourien) présente ce problème avec la subordonnée au présent. Il faut déterminer quelle solution est correcte.

Comment: @Chop L'utilisation du présent "est" sonne tellement faux à mon oreille, que je suis surpris que ce soit une option... je dois avoir un mauvais feeling :)

Comment: @Random En l'occurrence, je suis assez d'accord avec [la réponse de Puzzled](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14667/7224). La concordance des temps est toujours un sujet délicat. Et encore, ici, nous avons la chance de rester cantonnés à l'indicatif. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Vérité générale et concordance des temps

La concordance des temps peut être rompue par un présent de vérité générale lorsque la proposition principale est au passé<sup>1</sup> :

> Mes parents disaient que tout travail mérite son dû.

Imaginez la phrase si la concordance est respectée :

> Mes parents disaient que tout travail méritait son dû.

Cette phrase semble choquante. Parce que nous disons aussi de nos jours que « tout travail mérite son dû » ? Mais nous relatons ici un discours passé, alors pourquoi le relater au présent ? Parce que celui-ci est toujours vrai.

#### L'exemple de la question

Plus généralement, la source citée plus haut indique :

> Remarque : il se peut que le présent de l'indicatif soit employé dans une subordonnée dépendant d'un verbe principal au passé. C'est le cas s'il s'agit d'exprimer une **vérité générale**, valable quelle que soit l'époque considérée.

La date d'anniversaire de Julia n'est probablement pas une vérité aussi générale que le dicton utilisé ici en exemple, mais c'est une vérité qui n'a pas changé entre le moment passé et le moment présent et qui ne changera jamais.

Le présent de vérité générale est donc de mise ici :

> Hier, je ne savais pas quand est l’anniversaire de Julia.

Cette phrase semble choquante à l'oreille, mais ceci est plus dû aux choix des mots que du temps :

> L'anniversaire de Julia est après-demain.

Cette tournure n'est pas ce qu'il y a de plus agréable à l'oreille. On peut imaginer d'autres tournures n'utilisant pas le verbe « être » :

> Hier, je ne savais pas quand Julia est née.
>   Hier, je ne savais pas à quelle date a lieu l'anniversaire de Julia.

À noter que le site [Slate.fr](http://www.slate.fr/story/100341/probleme-maths-singapourien) (qui bénéficie déjà d'une certaine renommée, ce qui n'est certes pas toujours gage de qualité mais est toujours un signe encourageant) présente ce problème en utilisant le présent pour la subordonnée :

> Au début je ne savais pas quand est l’anniversaire de Cheryl, mais maintenant je sais.

#### Lever le doute sur le verbe

Si la conjugaison du verbe est un trop grand problème, [Puzzled propose très intelligemment](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14667/7224) de reformuler la phrase :

> Hier, je ne connaissais pas la date d'anniversaire de Julia.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Source: http://www.cap-concours.fr/sanitaire-et-social/concours-paramedicaux/reviser/maitriser-la-concordance-des-temps-cc_fra_20</sub>

Comment: Si on veut que les répondants s'améliorent, il faut expliquer pourquoi on downvote. Merci.

Comment: Aucun des exemples fournis ne semble convaincant pour l'usage du présent dans le cas de l'anniversaire, d'un point de vue intuitif. Du point de vue de la structure de l'argument lui-même, les exemples comme *mes parents disaient que toute peine mérite salaire* sont des complétives simples tandis que la phrase proposée a l'air d'être une question indirecte. Il n'y a pas de raison a priori que ces deux types utilisent les mêmes concordances. Je n'ai pas voté -1.

Comment: @GAMPUB Je suis d'accord sur la nature discutable des exemples, mais ce n'est pas le point principal selon moi. Pour faire court, on m'a toujours enseigné (mais on m'a parfois enseigné des fautes) que la vérité générale s'exprime au présent de l'indicatif _y compris dans un récit passé_. Une date d'anniversaire _est_ une vérité générale : je suis né le 3 brumaire et chaque année, mon anniversaire est le 3 brumaire. Il semble ridicule (et peu naturel) de me demander quand était mon anniversaire passé (à moins de parler de la date à laquelle je l'ai célébré avec mes amis).

Comment: D'accord mais une question directe ou indirecte n'est pas une vérité générale...

Comment: @GAMPUB Merci, je comprends mieux le problème. Aurions-nous une référence pour nous départager sur ce sujet ? Je ne trouve rien de concluant. Le point me paraît toutefois discutable : l'intervenant en ignore la valeur exacte mais il sait que cette date est unique et immuable. Une vérité cesse-t-elle d'être vraie (tout du moins en grammaire) parce que j'en ignore les détails ?

Comment: Une question par nature n'est ni vraie ni fausse

Answer (score 5):

As a french native, I'd tend to say that both are fine, and would not feel strange.
However, in this case, I would use the present "est", because it is a general statement.

If Julia's birthday were yesterday and I missed it because I did not know it, then I'd use the past "était", because I would refer to this year's birthday, which is past.

To remove any ambiguity, you might want to rephrase :

> Au début, je ne connaissais pas la date d'anniversaire de Julia, mais maintenant je la connais.

Answer (score 5):

Honnêtement j'utiliserais :

> Hier je ne savais pas quand était l’anniversaire de Julia.

L'autre phrase se dit mal. En fait je n'ai jamais vraiment entendu la première phrase.

Comment: Vous ne pouvez dire cela que lorsque vous avez raté de vous rendre à l'anniversaire de quelqu'un : "Hier, je ne savais pas quand était l'anniversaire (quand est-ce que l'on fêtait l'anniversaire) de Julia, et donc je n'ai pu m'y rendre ; aujourd'hui je sais quand est son anniversaire".

Answer (score 1):

***Illustration*** par l'exemple

- Hier je ne savais pas *quand est* l'anniversaire de Julia.
- Aujourd'hui je ne sais pas *quand est* l'anniversaire de Julia.
- Un jour, peut-être, je saurai *quand est* l'anniversaire de Julia.
- Vous me disiez que l'anniversaire de Julia *est* le 30 février ? Étrange !
- Je savais, je sais et donc je saurai aussi demain *quand est* l'anniversaire de J.-S. Bach, c'est le 31 mars ; celui de sa mort *est* le 28 juillet.
- Avant que la commune change la date de célébration de la *Fête annuelle du coin*, je savais *quand était* l'anniversaire de cette fête, le troisième dimanche de juin, puisque je m'y rendais. Aujourd'hui *c'est* le second équinoxe.
- Madame, lorsque votre enfant sera né, vous saurez *quand est* (puisqu'à ce moment il aura poussé son premier cri)  son anniversaire ; vous saurez *quelle sera* sa date (remplace *quand* : une date change chaque jour, c'est *anniversaire* qui la qualifie) anniversaire (qui est invariable : *c'est* le énième jour du nième<sup>1</sup> mois ).
- Le 18 brumaire *était l'anniversaire* du coup d'état napoléonien pour le calendrier de l'époque ; aujourd'hui, le 9 novembre *est l'anniversaire* de cet événement.
- Si l'anniversaire de Julia *est* le 29 février, il *sera* donc fêté la prochaine année bissextile.
- L'anniversaire de Julia *est* le 30 février, je n'y étais pas, je ne savais pas *quand **il** était* célébré (Ce n'était **l**'anniversaire de Julia, mais **un** anniversaire de Julia).
- Je ne sais pas *quand on fêtera* (futur : il s'agit d'un anniversaire à fêter parmi d'autres) le prochain anniversaire de Julia (soit je ne connais pas la date, soit Julia ne fête pas le jour-même son anniversaire, mais le fait le week-end suivant).
- Je ne sais pas *quand sera* [fêté] le prochain (on parle toujours d'un seul anniversaire) anniversaire de Julia.
- Son dernier anniversaire *aurait été* (conditionnel passé) complètement raté (c'est ce que j'ai entendu dire, mais je n'y étais pas).
- Son dernier anniversaire *avait été* (plus-que-parfait) parfait (on ne peut pas mettre le présent sur une situation terminée et passée).
- Je ne pouvais pas savoir que son prochain anniversaire *a été* réussi.

  ---

<sup>Il y a sûrement d'autres cas de figure ; cette réponse peut être complétée.</sup>

<sup>1 - *énième* ou *nième* : d'ordre puissance *n* → *n<sup>ième</sup>*</sup>

Comment: Pour l’usage de “quel/le + future” (en place de “quand”) quand une date change/peut changer, serait-il possible de dire « **quand** + future » si l’on parle spécifiquement de « son **prochain** anniversaire » (Hier, je ne savais pas quand sera[-t-il] son prochain anniversaire), vu que l’année (et donc la date complète) change (et donc, par extension, l’imparfait [était]  en parlant spécifiquement de son **dernier** anniversaire, [?soit raté ou pas?]) (et re-donc, le présent [est] si l’on en parle en général, sans spécification, sans risque de changer, comme dans l’exemple de l’OP) ?

Comment: @PapaPoule J'ai ajouté quelques exemples pour tenir compte de votre commentaire, dites-moi s'il manque encore quelque chose

Comment: Non, c’est clair, merci! L’importance de la distinction entre **L**’anniversaire (qui est fixe, comme la date de naissance … une vérité générale, quoi, comme disait Chop) et **UN** anniversaire (soit le premier, dernier, prochain, etc) m’échappait au début, mais je la pige maintenant. (mais pour jouer l’avocat du diable, est-ce que **L**’anniversaire de quelqu’un qui est né le 29 février EST le 29 février pour appliquer cette distinction entre **son** anniversaire & **UN** [de ses] anniversaire[s] dans les années non-bissextiles même s’il le fête sur le 1ere mars [= le 28 février +1]?)

Comment: @PapaPoule - L'anniversaire est le 29, les parents charitables offrent des cadeaux le 28 puisqu'ils considèrent le mois de naissance, d'autres le 1er mars, anniversaire réel si on décompte le nombre de jours depuis le premier de l'an, les radins le font tous les quatre ans, sauf les années d'exceptions (divisibles par 100 ou 400) - L'administration décompte à l'année, vous vieillissez tout pareil ; la vie se moque de nos complications cérébrales pour dire comment la terne tourne. D'autres ont des calendriers lunaires !

Comment: Quel est le justificatif du vote négatif ?

Comment: @cl-r Comme PapaPoule, la vision générique de l'anniversaire m'échappait dans la première phrase mais elle peut se comprendre dans le contexte d'une énigme. Avec une lecture spécifique de l'anniversaire (le prochain), la concordance proposée paraît étrange. Les exemples donnés avec les anniversaires de la naissance ou de la mort de gens célèbres sont convaincants mais ça reste difficile avec Julia dont la notoriété n'est pas parvenue jusqu'à moi. Je n'ai pas voté -1.

Comment: @GAMPUB J’ai découvert que l'on pense d'abord à *[la date de] l'anniversaire [de qqn]* et donc au prochain ou au précédent anniversaire, car dans l'usage habituel, on le relie aux cadeaux ; donc, on va fêter (ou on a fêté) *un* anniversaire. Mais si on relie *anniversaire* à *date de naissance* :" C'est (et non pas c'était) quand la date de naissance de Julia ?", même si elle n'est pas morte, le présent vient plus spontanément. Ce n'est pas une question de notoriété, mais de changement de point de vue, et comme ce dernier est plus rarement utilisé, il y a quelque chose qui surprend l'oreille.